# Dictionary of lists and list of tuples comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I am trying to get my dictionary of lists to match up with my list of tuples. (hopefully that makes sense). I have a dictionary with lists as the values, my values are individual scores for each book, ex: the value 5 on bob would equal the first book in the book list, :

```
d = {'bob':[5,0,0,1,3], 'toms':[3,0,5,3,0], 'sammy': [0,0,0,1,0], 'ted':[5,0,0,6,3]}
```

and a list of tuples:

```
books=[('Douglas Adams', "The Hitchhiker"), ('Richard Adams', 'Watership'), ('Mitch Albom', 'The Five People'), ('Laurie Anderson', 'Speak'), ('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings')]
```

So what I would like is to be able to be able to some how say when someone has a value of 3 or 6 I can pull them out to say what books have those ratings.
Thanks!

Edit:
I would like it to output a dictionary of some sort where it would say:

```
selectScores = {bob: ('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings'), toms: (Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings', Laurie Anderson', 'Speak')}
```

and so on for each person

something like that I would hope to be the output.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help writing the code, what have you already tried? SO is not a code-writing service, but we're happy to help you write code. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, perhaps you could [edit] to include your expected output, and _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research to make a [mcve]

Comment: can you add some expected output? I don't really understand what you mean by "when someone has a value of 3 or 6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Basically enumerate the dictionary values and use it's index to access the books array.

```
d = {'bob':[5,0,0,1,3], 'toms':[3,0,5,3,0], 'sammy': [0,0,0,1,0], 'ted':[5,0,0,6,3]}
books=[('Douglas Adams', "The Hitchhiker"), ('Richard Adams', 'Watership'), ('Mitch Albom', 'The Five People'), ('Laurie Anderson', 'Speak'), ('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings')]

select_scores = {}
for key, books_scores in d.items():
    for i, score in enumerate(books_scores):
        if score == 3 or score == 6:
            if key not in select_scores:
                select_scores[key] = []
            select_scores[key].append(books[i])
            
print(select_scores)
```

Output:

```
{'bob': [('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings')], 'toms': [('Douglas Adams', 'The Hitchhiker'), ('Laurie Anderson', 'Speak')], 'ted': [('Laurie Anderson', 'Speak'), ('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings')]}
```